# Remove duplicate numbers in Java 8 and get the sum

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda

I am trying to remove the duplicate numbers in java 8 including the number of reference. For example I have an array with values like (2,3,2,5)

All number 2's should be removed and the numbers should remain are 3 and 5.
So the expected sum is 8. However in my code below, it still gets the 2. It did remove the duplicate number but still retain the number reference.

Here is my code.

```
List<Integer> clearedNumbers = numbers.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    int sum = clearedNumbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
```

The sum I am getting is 10 instead of 8.

Comment: You would need to create a frequency histogram and then sum the ones with frequency 1

Comment: The first line is easier and more readable to do using a `Set`.

Comment: The sum you're getting is correct because it removed duplicates and sum operation is performed, what you want is remove all the numbers with frequency more than one and perform sum operation.

Comment: `distinct` will keep *one* 2, obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a little bit smarter... (whenever you have a duplicate just map that to `zero` via the `combiner`):

```
int result = Stream.of(2, 3, 2, 5)
            .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            Function.identity(),
                            Function.identity(),
                            (x, y) -> 0),
                    map -> map.values().stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum()))
```

Comment: Hi Eugene! This is smarter, indeed. But IMO it's not expressive, I mean the intention is not clear, you need some advanced understanding to catch this.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner I feel sooo much smarter when you say "advanced" ))

Comment: Well, *advanced* is relative. You got my point, I upvoted anyways, because your answer is correct and efficient, while the accepted answer and most of the other ones are `O(n^2)`, because they use `Collections.frequency` or `List.contains` inside a `Stream.filter` or a `for` loop. Your answer is not Holger-advanced, though ;)

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner not even close... agreed.

Answer (score 5):

I would collect count of each number, and sum only singles :

```
 System.out.println(
         Stream.of(2,3,2,5)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getValue() == 1)
                .mapToInt(Map.Entry::getKey)
                .sum());
```

Outputs 8

Comment: you can do a little bit smarter than that https://stackoverflow.com/a/48883475/1059372

Answer (score 0):

The sum you're getting is correct because it removed duplicates and sum operation is performed, what you want is remove all the numbers with frequency more than one and perform sum operation. Try this.

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(5);

    List<Integer> clearedNumbers = numbers.stream().filter(num -> {
        return Collections.frequency(numbers, num) == 1;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
    int sum = clearedNumbers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).sum();
    System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: @OlaTorres you have probably picked the worst performance wise answer, which is your option, obviously.

Comment: Please don't use `Collections.frequency` inside filter, as this yields `O(n^2)` complexity.

Comment: @Eugene oh... sorry about that.. do you have a suggestion on how I can achieve the result without using frequency? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @OlaTorres you have nothing to be sorry for, it is your choice to accept any answer you want, and notice that this answer is *correct*, it *slower*. And I am also a little biased here, since I provided an answer too... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48883475/1059372

Answer (score 0):

Why not apply simple approach as create another array list without the current element and compare. If compare returns false then add them. Look at below code snippet :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        a.add(2);
        a.add(2);
        a.add(3);
        a.add(5);
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < a.size(); i++) {
            b.clear();
            for(int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
                if(j != i) 
                    b.add(a.get(j));
            }
            if(! b.contains(a.get(i)))
                sum = sum + a.get(i);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
```

It can give the desired result.

Comment: Please don't use `List.contains` inside your for loop, as this yields `O(n^2)` complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Collections.Frequency API,

```
 System.out.println(numbers.stream()
                .filter(i -> Collections.frequency(numbers, i)==1)
                .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                .sum());
```

Comment: how many times you are iterating to get the frequency for each elements, how do you think?

Comment: Please don't use `Collections.frequency` inside filter, as this yields `O(n^2)` complexity.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner yes, I agree